# fast range summable hash functions

Tags: ds.algorithms, coding-theory, hash-function

I'm finding is there any range summable hash function.

ADD: The hash function I refer to is the one that is typically used in tug-of-war sketch(AMS sketch). Please refer to [The space complexity of approximating the frequency moments](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=237823).

[Improved range-summable random variable construction algorithms](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=776779) gives one for any k-wise independence, 
but its author [Martin J. Strauss](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~martinjs/) shows it is [incorrect](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~martinjs/papers/ll-2005.pdf) from his homepage.

The only one I can find is from [One-Pass Wavelet Decompositions of Data Streams](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1070550), where a 4-wise one is given. It used second-order Reed-Muller hash functions.

Are there any other range summable hash functions with 4 or more independence?

Comment: the first paper you reference has quite a few other references on page 3.

Comment: Please note that csthoery is a Q&A, not a discussion forum. ps: I think it would be helpful if you clarify what you exactly mean by a hash function since it is used to refer to various kind of objects.

Comment: thanks for you help. I have modified a little to make it clear. The "Improved" one is incorrect, not "one-pass" one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the newest one that gives 7-wise independence using MR code, also two others based on BCH and EH code with 3-wise independence. They are tested to be good enough for AMS sketch in [this paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1242528)